# How to save the registers value using inline Assembler

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86

(Well,this is the first time i ask questions here and English isn't my first language,so please forgive some of my mistakes. And i'm a green hand in programme.)

I met this problem while doing my OS homework, we were asked to simulate the function [SwitchToFiber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686350%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),and my current problem is i don't know how to save the registers value in order to recover the function next time it was called.

I don't know if my problem was clear. Though i don't think my code was useful, i will put them below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define INVALID_THD NULL
#define N 5
#define REG_NUM 32
unsigned store[N][REG_NUM];
typedef struct
{
    void (*address) (void * arg);
    void* argu;
}thread_s;

thread_s ts[N];

void StartThds();
void YieldThd();
void *CreateThd(void (*ThdFunc)(void*), void * arg);
void thd1(void * arg);
void thd2(void * arg);
void StartThds()
{

}

void YieldThd()
{
    thd2((void*)2);

}

void *CreateThd(void (*ThdFunc)(void*), void * arg)
{
    ts[(int)arg].address = (*ThdFunc);
    ts[(int)arg].argu = arg;
}

void thd2(void * arg)
{
    for (int i = 4; i < 12; i++)
    {
        printf("\tthd2: arg=%d , i = %d\n", (int)arg, i);
        //in order to see clearly，i added /t abouve
        YieldThd();
    }
}

void thd1(void * arg)
{
/* 
    __asm__(

    );
*/ 
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        printf("thd1: arg=%d , i = %d\n", (int)arg, i);
        YieldThd();
    }
}

int main()
{
    //this is my first plan, to store the register value in some static arry 
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j<REG_NUM; j++)
            store[i][j] = 0;
    //create the two thread 
    if (CreateThd(thd1, (void *)1) == INVALID_THD)
    {
        printf("cannot create\n");
    }
    if (CreateThd(thd2, (void *)2) == INVALID_THD)
    {
        printf("cannot create\n");
    }


    ts[1].address(ts[1].argu);      //thd1((void*)1),argu = 1； 
//  StartThds();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the whole code now i have,because i don't know which part maybe useful, so i put them all above. As you can see, most of them are still empty.

Comment: What CPU are we talking about? And where's your assembly code? Btw, this looks awfully like implementing C's `setjmp()`/`longjmp()` (hint).

Comment: well, my CPU seems to be Pentium4, and i am using C-FREE compile.I don't know even how to begin my assembly code,so there is nothing.

Comment: Then how about learning some assembly and coming back with specific questions?

Comment: And my teacher did said that i should take a look at longjmp().

Comment: I have learned assembly language, what i don't know is how to using them in C and how to use them to save the register value.

Comment: In that case see your compiler documentation for syntax and examples. Or look for examples online.

Comment: I have search the internet for almost two days and have find nothing useful, that why i ask the question here.

Comment: I understand, c-free is only an IDE. What compiler are you using with it? (hint #2)

Comment: i don't know what do you mean, how can i check that?

Comment: See c-free's options/configuration for compiler name (executable name). Or ask your teacher and/or classmates.

Comment: Which is gcc. Now you can find gcc inline assembly tutorials and source code for setjmp() and longjmp().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible (as pointed out in comments) that you don't need to write assembly for this, perhaps you can get away with just using `setjmp()/longjmp()`, and have them do the necessary state-saving.

Comment: I was planned to create the user-level thread and then simulate the schedule, my teacher said that only the 'setjmp()/longjmp()' isn't enough, and using the assebly to save the registers is necessary.

Comment: Only if he's switching between 2 threads. If it's 3 you have to store/restore yourself.

Comment: Yeah,what i want to i can simulate more than 2,so i think assebly is necessary but i don't know how...

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before but i always have to look up the details. The following is of course just pseudo-code.

basically what you do is you create a struct with your registers:

```
typedef struct regs {
   int ebx; //make sure these have the right size for the processors.
   int ecx;
   //...  for all registers you wish to backup
} registers;

//when changing from one thread
asm( //assembly varies from compiler to compiler check your manual
  "mov ebx, thread1.register.ebx;
   mov ecx, thread1.register.ecx;"
  // and so on

  //very important store the current program counter to the return address of this fu nction so we can continue from ther
  // you must know where the return address is stored
  "mov return address, thread1.register.ret"
);

//restore the other threads registers
asm(
  "mov thread2.register.ebx, ebx;
   mov thread2.register.ecx, ecx;
   //now restoer the pc and let it run
   mov thread2.register.ret, pc; //this will continue from where we stopped before
);
```

This is more or less the principle of how it works. Since you are learning this you should be able to figure out the rest on your own.

Comment: Thank you very much for your direction! I will try my best to do it.